# Is there any difference between UCB(Upper Bound Confidence) and UCB1(Upper Bound Confidence1)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bayesian, optimization, reinforcement-learning

While studying Multi-Armed Bandit, I have seen UCB and UCB1 and wonder if they are two difference things. The formulas look similar but the thing is they look slightly different.

1. UCB ==> $ A_t = argmax [Q_t(a) + c\sqrt\frac{\log t}{N_t(a)}] $
2. UCB1 ==> $ A_t = argmax [Q_t(a) + \sqrt\frac{2\log t}{N_t(a)}] $

They look almost identical and the only differences are the constant before the square root of UCB and the number, 2, in the nominator inside the square root of UCB1.

Hope to hear some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the link.